# Check that integer type belongs to enum member

Tags: c#

I want to check that some integer type belongs to (an) enumeration member.

For Example,

```
public enum Enum1
{
    member1 = 4,

    member2 = 5,

    member3 = 9,

    member4 = 0
}
```

Enum1 e1 = (Enum1)4 gives me member1

Enum1 e2 = (Enum1)10 gives me nothing and I want to check it.

Comment: What do you want to check...?

Comment: Don't know your purpose of using a enum anyways. Try if you could use a Dictionary instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate Enum Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615/validate-enum-values)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Use `Enum.IsDefined`

```
Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Enum1), 4) == true
```

but

```
Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Enum1), 1) == false
```

Comment: Don't use this if you require speed: Enum.IsDefined uses Reflection and is **very** slow.

Comment: First, micro-optimization is a waste of programming effort.  Second, `Enum.IsDefined` will run over 2,000 times per millisecond.  I wouldn't consider that slow.

Comment: ereOn, How can I make it faster ?

Comment: @Sam: I precised *"if you require speed"*. If you do this in, for example, a network frame treatment loop, you might get terrible results in the end.
@Alexander Stalt: Unless you check each value one by one, you can't I suppose. But that's overkill (in terms of code length). The real question is: is such a test really needed ? Usually, a switch statement handling all the possible values and a *"default"* one is enough. But we obviously lack of information to discuss that here (and it's probably off-topic)

Comment: @ereOn, I have an xml file. I store my program settings there. Some settings are enumeration types, so i save (int)Enum1.member1. When I load that file, I must to check if some settings correct because someone else could change them.

Comment: If you only load (and parse) that XML file once (or not very often), you can just use Sam's solution: even if Enum.IsDefined is slow, it is probably still way faster than the I/O operation on your XML file, so not really a problem here imho.

Comment: Is speed is a problem, simply cache the results.

Comment: @ereOn, If speed is so much of a concern that `Enum.IsDefined` is too slow for a particular application, then .NET is not the right choice in the first place.

Comment: So it is ok to write badly-designed/unoptimized code because C# is *slow* anyway ? I tend to agree on the fact that micro-optimization often doesn't pay as much as it costs. But avoiding reflection when it is not **really** needed is **not** a waste of programming effort. 2000 times/ms (on *your* computer for which we don't know the specifications) is *slow* for something as simple as a 32/64 bits matching process. I however admit that in this very case (and in most cases), it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @ereOn, `Enum.IsDefined` **is not slow**.  You'd be better off outlawing `String.Format` since [on my laptop] it can only be run 931 times per millisecond which is nothing compared to `Enum.IsDefined`'s 2000+ calls.

Comment: @ere, there are times when micro-optimization is important.  In our own application we had to replace all `String.Format` calls within the context of our reports and use `String.Concat` instead.  We only did this in the one place that the profiler showed it was needed and it made a noticeable difference over the several hundred thousand iterations done for each report.  However, this experience wouldn't drive me to tell other people to avoid `String.Format` all the time.

Comment: You're obviously missing the point. Maybe you should compare performances between `Enum.IsDefined` and another method that doesn't use reflection. Your performances results are pointless, since we don't know your computer specifications and have **nothing** to compare them with. Anyway, my first comment stated **"if you require speed"** which is an important **if**. So again, avoid using this method if speed is an important requirement. `Enum.IsDefined` **is** slow regarding what it does and how he does it ;)

Comment: @ereOn, I would say the exact same thing, you're missing the point.  This whole thing blanket **if you require speed** is ridiculous.  You scared the OP into not using `Enum.IsDefined` when it's probably the most appropriate option for his situation.  The question is if a particular statement is used in a way that would degrade performance in a meaningful way.  Comparing `Enum.IsDefined` to *32/64 bit matching process* is completely irrelevant since you first need to get all the values to compare against which would require hard coding them again in a `switch` or using `Enum.GetValues`.

Comment: I'm sorry if I somehow offended you by warning the OP about the possible slowness of your method **in some particular situations**. I agree with your answer ! However, efficient coding *sometimes* require to write a few lines: not everything can be done in one call ;) If the OP doesn't require very high performance and prefers code simplicity, then your solution is **just perfect**. And that's what I said in my third comment. I often use `Enum.IsDefined` method myself, but I wouldn't in some particular cases. Anyway, the OP accepted your answer (and I even upvoted it) so... ;)

Answer (score 5):

As Sam says, you can use IsDefined. This is somewhat awkward though. You *may* want to look at my [Unconstrained Melody](http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody) library which would let you us:

```
Enum1 e2 = (Enum1)10;
if (e2.IsNamedValue()) // Will return false
{
}
```

It's probably not worth it for a single enum call, but if you're doing a lot of stuff with enums you may find some useful things in there.

It should be quicker than `Enum.IsDefined` btw. It only does a linear scan at the moment, but let me know if you need that to be improved :) (Most enums are small enough that they probably wouldn't benefit from a `HashSet`, but we could do a binary search...)

Answer (score 3):

```
int testNum = 5;
bool isMember = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Enum1)).Cast<int>().Any(x => x == testNum);
```

Answer (score 1):

You look through the values of the enum and compare them to the integer.

```
    static bool EnumTest(int testVal, Enum e)
    {
        bool result = false;
        foreach (var val in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Enum1)))
        {
            if ((int)val == testVal)
            {
                result = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

**Edit**: Looks like Sam has a [better solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605386/check-that-integer-type-belongs-to-enum-member/2605417#2605417).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Enum.GetValues to get all defined values. Then check if your value exists in that list.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Be careful this won't work if you have an enum for 3 (Apples and Pears) the methods above won't detect it as valid.

```
[Flags]
public enum Fruit
{ 

    Apples=1,

    Pears=2,

    Oranges =4,

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a succinct little snippet from an extension method I wrote a few years ago. Combines TryParse with IsDefined to do it all in one swoop and handle values that don't exist in the enum.

```
if (value != null)
{
    TEnum result;
    if (Enum.TryParse(value.ToString(), true, out result))
    {
        // since an out-of-range int can be cast to TEnum, double-check that result is valid
        if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(TEnum), result.ToString() ?? string.Empty))
        {
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the extension for integer values

```
public static TEnum ParseToEnum<TEnum>(this int value, TEnum? defaultValue = null, bool useEnumDefault = false) where TEnum : struct
{
    return ParseToEnumInternal(value, defaultValue, useEnumDefault);
}
```

And a usage

```
public enum Test
{
    Value1 = 1,
    Value2 = 3
}
    
var intValue = 1;
var enumParsed = intValue.ParseToEnum<Test>(); // converts to Test.Value1
intValue = 2;
enumParsed = intValue.ParseToEnum<Test>(); // either throws or converts to supplied default
enumParsed = 3.ParseToEnum<Test>(); // converts to Test.Value2
```

Some people don't like how it dangles off the end of the (potentially nullable) value, but I have an extension that handles null values of nullable types (int?) and I like it myself, so ...

I can post like a Gist of the whole extension method with all the overloads if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Fruit),e2))
{
   //Valid Value
}
else
{
   //Invalid ENum Value
}
```

Comment: How does this add to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2605417/3744182) of [Samuel Neff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118703/samuel-neff) which suggests, *Use `Enum.IsDefined`: `Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Enum1), 4) == true`* ?

Comment: I am showing a different way to answer the question of this original post: "Check that integer type belongs to enum member". I didn't see anyone who posted this response to the question. I think that this is the cleanest way and is also accurate to know if an integer is in the enum that is all.

Answer (score 0):

Found this useful. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64374930/16803533

no need to use IsDefined and No range checking