# Enum.Parse does not trigger exception when expected

Tags: c#, .net

Say that I have this Enum:

```
enum GradeEnum
{
    A = 1,
    B = 2,
    C = 3,
}
```

Then I do

`GradeEnum grade = (GradeEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(GradeEnum),"234");`

Then there no error triggered and the grade variable value is `234`. But if I do comparaison with value of GradeEnum as expected the `grade` variable has not matched value.

Question, why is there no exception trigger by the `Parse` method?

Comment: That's how enums work, you can give them any value you like, they're really just `int` (most of the time)

Comment: Even stranger is: `enum GradeEnum{  A = 1,   B = 2,   C = 3} ... GradeEnum g = (GradeEnum) 4;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `Enum.IsDefined` to check whether enum is defined or not.

In order to parse and also validate you need both methods.

```
GradeEnum grade = (GradeEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(GradeEnum), "234");
if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(GradeEnum), grade))
    ; // throw exception
```

Or use TryParse mentioned in comment bellow, forgot that!

```
string gradeValue = "234";
GradeEnum grade;
if (Enum.TryParse(gradeValue, out grade))
{
    // success
}
```

Comment: Ok, why not `Enum.TryParse`?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: _" why is there no exception trigger by the Parse method?"_  But it was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741649/enum-tryparse-returns-true-for-any-numeric-values)