# How to effectively validate an integer that represents a flagged enumeration?

Tags: c#, validation, bit-manipulation, enumeration, flags

Consider [`FileAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes.aspx) enumeration which is designed for bitwise operations. I've created a system in which, user selects some checkboxes to determine the status of a file. A file may be both `ReadOnly` and `System`. Thus the value would be 5 (1 for `ReadOnly` and 4 four `System`).

How can I validate an integer to be a valid `FileAttributes` enumeration?

I've seen these questions, but they didn't help me, as they don't work for bitwised (flagged, combined) values.

[Check that integer type belongs to enum member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605386/check-that-integer-type-belongs-to-enum-member)
[Is there a way to check if int is legal enum in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674730/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-int-is-legal-enum-in-c)

Comment: If **any** combination of flags is valid you can simply check if each bit set to 1 in the `enum` value is a valid `enum` item (with a simple `for` and bitwise AND).

Comment: In case you need an example of this just look the source code of `Enum.InternalFlagsFormat()` method (you won't build a string but you'll check if that value is valid).

Comment: What if for any reason, the enumeration is not well-designed? For example it doesn't have `1`? In that case, 5 returns true, while 1 doesn't exist.

Comment: @SaeedNeanmati you loop through bits of the **given** value. If, say, enumeration has these values: 2, 4, 8 and you give 5 what you'll do is a for that will result in 1, 2, 4, 8, etc. In this case if 2, 8, etc. aren't set so they'll skipped. 4 is valid but when you'll check if "1" (because it's set) is a valid enum value you'll see it's not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- compute a cumulative bitwise "or" over all legal values (perhaps using Enum.GetValues)
- compute "testValue & ~allValues"
- if that is non-zero, then it is impossible to form your current value by combining the legal flags

Comment: Is that `~` the negative operator @Marc?

Comment: @SaeedNeamati bitwise "not" / "complement"

Answer (score 2):

This will work. Basically, if the enum combination is invalid, ToString() will just return the number.

```
private bool CombinationValidForFileAttributes(int value)
{
    return ((FileAttributes)value).ToString() != value.ToString();
}
```