# Is there a difference when converting an enum to a string between Convert.ToString() vs .ToString()?

Tags: c#, enums, tostring

Something amazed me with Enum String Conversion

If I do:

*(Edit: This assertion is contested - it is true only if an enum variable instance has an invalid value)*

```
Convert.ToString(MyEnum.MyEnumValue); // Returns Integer Representation
```

Whereas if I do

```
MyEnum.MyEnumValue.ToString(); // Returns `MyEnumValue`
```

Why is this behaviour or am I missing something?

Comment: How does your enum definition look like? :)

Comment: @Icepickle: Does it Matter? Any Enum (default it takes base as Integer) which you create would suffice your requirement.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the output. As you already stated. The first is a conversion and the second is an string representation of the object.

Comment: The implementation of `ToString()` is really interesting.

Comment: Please write a compilable repro, because when I try this, the behaviour you describe does NOT happen. In both cases, it returns `MyEnumValue` and NOT the integer representation.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: because with my program, i also do not get your described behavior :D

Comment: `ToString`  for object calss. but `Convert.ToString` is for `Convert` class. they have different implementations.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary no, basically they are the same. See the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,1801).

Comment: [Are you sure?](https://ideone.com/RVil1d)

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary sure you don't cast it to an `int` along the way?

Comment: ofc if you cast it to int it will return the number. but no i didnt cast to int. they both return enum value not int. @PatrickHofman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked code that should be run for both cases.
For Enum.ToString:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return Enum.InternalFormat((RuntimeType)base.GetType(), this.GetValue());
}
private static string InternalFormat(RuntimeType eT, object value)
{
    if (eT.IsDefined(typeof(FlagsAttribute), false))
    {
        return Enum.InternalFlagsFormat(eT, value);
    }
    string name = Enum.GetName(eT, value);
    if (name == null)
    {
        return value.ToString();
    }
    return name;
}
```

For Convert.ToString:

```
this.GetType().ToString();
```

So, it should work in a same way for both cases. Please provide your code.
Here is [sample](https://ideone.com/JIPKrL) from my side.

Comment: Please delete your answer as I want to delete the question. Also this should be a comment.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal you can delete if there is a non-positive answer scoring, right?

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Deleting will not happen if there is an answer. Scoring does not matter.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal Beyond 20K it doesn't matter. I can only vote to delete the question if it has a negative score, just like you. (not saying I would vote, just that I can vote)

Answer (score 0):

As per Anton's answer, the behaviour of `Convert.ToString` and `.ToString()` are on an enum is identical.

I believe what may have happened is that you assigned the `enum` variable an integral value which is out of range of the enumeration. Since enums are internally represented as [integral types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/enumeration-types), the backing type will generally have a much wider range than the enum states that have been defined for it.

Corruption of enum values can occur quite easily, for example during casting, during a deserialization step, or when using [enum parsing methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35117265/314291).

As a result, you should always validate that the enum is valid before trusting it in the rest of your system, e.g. through [Enum.IsDefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2674730/314291), although you'll need to do further work if you are using [FlagsAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8447/314291)

```
enum MyEnum
{
   Value1 = 1,
   Value2 = 2
};

void Main()
{
    // Literal
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(MyEnum.Value1)); // Value1
    Console.WriteLine(MyEnum.Value1.ToString()); // Value1

    // Variable
    MyEnum myEnum = MyEnum.Value2;
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(myEnum)); // Value2
    Console.WriteLine(myEnum.ToString());  // Value2

    // Invalid
    MyEnum badEnum = (MyEnum)123;
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(badEnum)); // 123
    Console.WriteLine(badEnum.ToString()); // 123
}
```