# C# Enum.TryParse parses invalid number strings

Tags: c#, enums

C# .NET 4.5, Windows 10, I have the following enum:

```
private enum Enums
{
    A=1, B=2, C=3
}
```

And this program behaves in a very strange way:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Enums e;
    if (Enum.TryParse("12", out e))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Parsed {0}", e);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.Write("Not parsed");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I would expect the result of the TryParse method to be false, but to my surprise 
the console shows "Parsed 12".
In the Watch window it even shows that the value is "12" and it is of the Enums type!

This is true for any number string that I tried (e.g. "540"), but not for strings that include letters ("A12", "12A").

I can easily overcome this by first checking if it's a number-only string, but why is this the behaviour?
Is it by design?

Thanks!
Ido

Comment: Yes, it is by design. It is a good idea that if `.ToString()` on a value can return a specific string, and the type in question has a `.Parse()` method, then the parse method should accept that string in return. Since enums can hold "unknown" values (ie. values that doesn't have a name in the enum), and `.ToString()` will return these as the number in a string, then it follows that `.Parse()` should accept a string holding only an integer number. So yes, this is by design. You may disagree with this decision but it is what it is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Internally, enums are stored as integers so that's likely why TryParse is returning true for integers being passed in.

Regarding why any integer is working, it's by design. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991317%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> When this method returns, result contains an object of type TEnum
>   whose value is represented by value if the parse operation succeeds.
>   If the parse operation fails, result contains the default value of the
>   underlying type of TEnum. **Note that this value need not be a member of
>   the TEnum enumeration**. This parameter is passed uninitialized.

Comment: Thanks!

I wasn't looking in the right place..
Also, apparently from the MSDN:

If this behavior is undesirable, call the IsDefined method to ensure that a particular string representation of an integer is actually a member of TEnum.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, using `IsDefined` would help if there's a chance that a non-member integer could be passed in. You could create an extension method that handles the `IsDefined` check for you after the parse so that you can use that method instead of the default `TryParse`.

Answer (score 7):

This method strictly parses integers to the range of the enum:

```
public static bool EnumTryParseStrict<TEnum>(string value, out TEnum result, bool ignoreCase = false) where TEnum : struct, Enum {
        if (Enum.TryParse(value, ignoreCase, out result) && Enum.IsDefined(typeof(TEnum), result)) {
            return true;
        }
        result = default;
        return false;
}
```

The method can be placed in a static class like this:

```
namespace IdentityStream { 
    public static class EnumUtil { 
        public static bool TryParseStrict<TEnum> ...
    }
}
```

result = default; assigns the default value of the underlying type of TEnum when the parse operation fails. This was done to comply with an expectation set by the Enum.TryParse contract:

> If the parse operation fails, result contains the default value of
> the underlying type of TEnum

Comment: This works,, but it breaks an expectation set by the Enum.TryParse contract: "If the parse operation fails, result contains the default value of the underlying type of TEnum"

Comment: If the strict parse operation fails, result now contains the default value of the underlying type of TEnum.

Comment: where to put this ? and what is the meaning of result=default ? your answer doesn't explain anything

Comment: @user1735921 I suggest you put it in static class:
namespace IdentityStream {
 public static class EnumUtil {
  public static bool TryParseStrict<TEnum>...

Comment: @user1735921 result = default; assigns the default value of the underlying type of TEnum when the parse operation fails.

Comment: I got it, thanks a lot, I have started using this. Can you edit your answer and mention the above in your answer ? then I can upvote it.

Answer (score 6):

A variable or field of an enumeration type can hold any values of its underlying type, so storing the value of 12 in a variable of type `Enums` in your case is entirely legal:

```
var e = (Enums) 12;
var i = (int) e; // i is 12
```

Therefore, `Enum.TryParse` must be able to parse any value of type `int` (or whichever underlying integer type used in your enumeration).

If you want to reject values having no representation in your enumeration, check them with `Enum.IsDefined`.