# How can I determine if a variable is assigned a value that is present in an Enum?

Tags: c#

I have this Enum:

```
namespace J.Enums
{
    public enum TH
    {
        Light = 0,
        Dark = 1
    }

    public static partial class Extensions
    {
        public static string Text(this TH theme)
        {
            switch (theme)
            {
                default:
                case TH.Light: return "Light";
                case TH.Dark: return "Dark";
            }
        }

        public static TH ToTheme(this string theme)
        {
            switch (theme)
            {
                default:
                case "Light": return TH.Light;
                case "Dark": return TH.Dark;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I have a variable `a` as follows:

```
var a = 88;
```

How can I determine if the value of a is a valid value for the Enum? Which in this case, it won't be.

Comment: Use [Enum.TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8)...

Comment: [Enum.IsDefined](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.isdefined?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Putting `default` above the other case labels seems odd.

Comment: Hi Amy,  Would it be better to have a different line with default: return TH.Light; I'm not sure if there's any difference but welcome your advice. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to check if int is legal enum in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674730/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-int-is-legal-enum-in-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var isDefined = Enum.IsDefined(typeof(TH), a);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works and will accept.  Unfortunately I now realise I have another problem but your answer was a big help.  I'll write up another question for the next problem I have.