# How to check If a Enum contain a number?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I have a Enum like this:

```
 public enum PromotionTypes
{
    Unspecified = 0, 
    InternalEvent = 1,
    ExternalEvent = 2,
    GeneralMailing = 3,  
    VisitBased = 4,
    PlayerIntroduction = 5,
    Hospitality = 6
}
```

I want to check if this Enum contain a number I give. For example: When I give 4, Enum contain that, So I want to return True, If I give 7, There isn't 7 in this Enum, So it returns False. 
I tried Enum.IsDefine but it only check the String value.
How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate Enum Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615/validate-enum-values)

Answer (score 257, accepted):

The `IsDefined` method requires *two parameters*. The ***first parameter is the type of the enumeration to be checked***. This type is usually obtained using a typeof expression. The ***second parameter is defined as a basic object***. It is used to specify either the integer value or a string containing the name of the constant to find. The return value is a Boolean that is true if the value exists and false if it does not.

```
enum Status
{
    OK = 0,
    Warning = 64,
    Error = 256
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool exists;

    // Testing for Integer Values
    exists = Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Status), 0);     // exists = true
    exists = Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Status), 1);     // exists = false

    // Testing for Constant Names
    exists = Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Status), "OK");      // exists = true
    exists = Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Status), "NotOK");   // exists = false
}
```

**[SOURCE](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/EnumIsDefined.aspx)**

Comment: Since .NET 5 you can use `bool Enum.IsDefined<TEnum>()` generic method.

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
IEnumerable<int> values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(PromotionTypes))
                              .OfType<PromotionTypes>()
                              .Select(s => (int)s);
if(values.Contains(yournumber))
{
      //...
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You should use `Enum.IsDefined`.

> I tried Enum.IsDefine but it only check the String value.

I'm 100% sure it will check both string value and int(the underlying) value, at least on my machine.

Comment: Thx, It's my mistakes, I forgot to convert the string to Int, so Enum.isDefined always get false when i gave the right number.

Comment: It definitely can take the (case-sensitive string representation) - see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.isdefined?view=netframework-4.7.1#remarks) or [the source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/enum.cs,32e813377ac50d28) for more info.

Comment: `if (Enum.IsDefined((CustomType)customTypeId)) { ... }` works great!

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you want to check and use the enum of the string value:

```
string strType;
if(Enum.TryParse(strType, out MyEnum myEnum))
{
    // use myEnum
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [Enums.NET package](https://github.com/TylerBrinkley/Enums.NET).

```
public enum PromotionTypes
{
    Unspecified = 0, 
    InternalEvent = 1,
    ExternalEvent = 2,
    GeneralMailing = 3,  
    VisitBased = 4,
    PlayerIntroduction = 5,
    Hospitality = 6
}

((PromotionTypes)4).IsValid() == true;
((PromotionTypes)7).IsValid() == false;
```