# Filter out value in foreach loop if it does not match any values in enum

Tags: c#, .net

How can I skip a value in a foreach loop if it does not match any of the values in an specific enum. Ex:

```
public enum IDs
{
    SomeIdOne = 1001,
    SomeIdTwo = 1002,
    SomeIdThree = 1003
}

// one of the list items(7777) does not match what's in the IDs enum
var SomeIds = new List<IDs>() { 1002,7777,1001 };

// skip that item when looping through the list.
foreach (IDs id in SomeIds)
{
    // do things with id
}
```

In the past I have used LINQ to filter out 0 in a similar situation, can I do something like that here?

Comment: You could execute a LINQ query against `SomeIds` and then `foreach` against that filtered list.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291953/how-to-check-if-a-enum-contain-a-number

Comment: @Setsu that seems to be asking a different question.

Comment: @Stavros_S No, it's asking the underlying question imbedded in yours. In order to filter out values not in the enum you must first be able to tell whether a particular value exists in the enum. Once you know that, your solution boils down to a simple if statement in the loop body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
foreach(var id in SomeIds.Where(x => Enum.IsDefined(typeof(IDs), x)))
{
    //....
}
```

If `SomeIds` is a list of integers, add `Cast`:

```
foreach(var id in SomeIds.Where(x => Enum.IsDefined(typeof(IDs), x)).Cast<IDs>())
```