# Enum with int value?

Tags: c#, enums

I want to make an `enum` for possible grades. This is a working example:

```
public enum Grade
{
    A, B, C, D, E, F
}
```

However, I want the grades to be integers, like

```
public enum Grade
{
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5
}
```

Why does the first one work but not the second? How can I make a similar variable that can only take values from 1-5 (and is nullable)?

Comment: Because an integer is not an **identifier**.

Comment: So how can I make a similar variable that can only take values from 1-5 (and is nullable)?

Comment: Incidentally it is not true that a variable of a enum type is incapable of holding values not listed by the enum, you can cast all sorts of crazy values to an enum.

Comment: See this on enum validation : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615/validate-enum-values

Comment: For the same reason you can't do: `string 1 = "hello";`

Answer (score 11):

You should specify `Grade` like this.

```
public enum Grade
{
    A = 1,
    B,
    C,
    D,
    E,
    F
}
```

B, C and so on will take next value.

Comment: @MarcGravell CS1059 The operand of an increment or decrement operator must be a variable, property or indexer

Answer (score 9):

enum elements need to have valid C# identifiers; `1`, `2`, `3` etc are not valid C# identifiers, so no: you can't do that. You can perhaps use `One = 1` etc,  or some common prefix (`Grade1`), but...

Answer (score 5):

C# requires `enum` constants to be *identifiers*, i.e. start in a letter/underscore, and include only letters, underscores, and digits.

You have multiple options to deal with this:

- Spell out the numbers - i.e. `Grade.One`, `Grade.Two`, etc.
- Prefix the number with a letter, or
- Prefix the number with an underscore.

In my opinion, the first option is the best, because it reads very well:

```
enum Grade {
    One = 1
,   Two
,   Three
,   Four
,   Five
}
```

The last option looks odd, but if you your mind is absolutely set on using numbers, this is as close as you can get to it:

```
enum Grade {
    _1 = 1 // Without =1 the value of _1 would be zero
,   _2
,   _3
,   _4
,   _5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the names you want to use for your enum of `{1, 2, 3, etc}` are invalid because they're not valid C# identifiers.

If you need those values out of your enum, you can do the following:

```
// Declare enum
public enum Grade
{
    A = 1,
    B,
    C,
    D,
    F
}
```

Then, when you need to access the value of say, `Grade.B`, you can do that like this:

```
int theIntGrade = (int)Grade.B  // after this line, theIntGrade will be equal to 2
```

Note that if you had a grade as a string, such as "C", you could convert it into an enumeration value like this:

```
Grade theLetterGrade = (Grade)Enum.Parse(typeof(Grade), "C", true); // final parameter sets case sensitivity for comparison
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make a similar variable that can only take values from 1-5 (and is nullable)?

Make your own type:

```
public struct Grade: IEquatable<Grade>
{
    private int innerValue;
    private int InnerValue => isInitialized ? innerValue : 1;
    private readonly bool isInitialized;

    private Grade(int value)
    {
        if (value < 1 || value > 5)
            throw new OverflowException();

        innerValue = value;
        isInitialized = true;
    }

    public static implicit operator Grade(int i) => new Grade(i);
    public static explicit operator int(Grade g) =>  g.InnerValue;
    public override bool Equals(object obj) => obj is Grade && Equals((Grade)obj);
    public bool Equals(Grade other) => InnerValue == other.InnerValue;
    public override int GetHashCode() => InnerValue.GetHashCode();
    public override string ToString() => InnerValue.ToString();
    public static bool operator ==(Grade left, Grade right) => left.Equals(right);
    public static bool operator !=(Grade left, Grade right) => !left.Equals(right);
}
```

Now you have a type than can only hold `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` and `5` and defaults to `1`. Initializing it is as simple as `Grade g = 4;`.

You need it to be nullable? No sweat: `Grade? g = 4;`.